# How to check if the current activity is the main/launcher activity in java

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

Is there any method such as `isMainActivity()` to detect the main/launcher activity in Android?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The manifest tells us which one is the main/launcher activity in Android. It does that through an intent-filter.

Comment: @cantoraz you wanted to check your intent at run time?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String action = intent.getAction();             
Set<String> categories = intent.getCategories();
```

Then, with that info you can check if your current activity is your MAIN/LAUNCHER activity.